# What's wrong with my Python code? I'm trying to deep-reverse a list input

Tags: python

```
def is_list(p):

    return isinstance(p, list)


def deep_reverse(list):

    o=[]
    for i in reversed(list):

        if is_list(i)==True:
            print i
            deep_reverse(i)

        o.append(i)

    return o
```

For example:

```
p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6]]]]
print deep_reverse(p)
#>>> [[[[6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]
```

Comment: To start, You never actually do anything with the return value of `deep_reverse` when you recurse.

Comment: you code is simply doing : `p[::-1]`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: But that's not what it's trying to do (`p[::-1]` would not give the desired output of `[[[[6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]`).

Comment: @DavidRobinson I mean the wrong version, not the corrected version.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: I don't see why that's helpful, since the OP knows it's not doing what he wants. If the wrong version didn't reverse anything, would you say "your code is simply doing `p`"?

Comment: @Rachit_Goel list is a reserved python word. Just for future reference. You can use it to test if you dont overwrite it (if type([]) is list:) <-- will always return true

Comment: @PaulSeeb -- Typically, it's thought to be more "pythonic" to use: `isinstance([],list)` than `type([]) is list`.  The reason for this is that `isinstance` will pass though subclasses as well, but the `type is` idiom won't -- Or, in terms of duck typing, `isinstance` is slightly more ducky :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the line

```
        deep_reverse(i)
```

to

```
        i = deep_reverse(i)
```

Incidentally, a shorter way to write this function would be:

```
def deep_reverse(lst):
    if not is_list(lst):
        return lst
    return map(deep_reverse, reversed(lst))
```

Comment: Note that this creates a copy, which may or may not be what you intended.  If you mean to reverse the list in place, you'll need a different solution.

Comment: @sr2222: I don't think the OP was trying to reverse the list in place, or he wouldn't have the line `print deep_reverse(p)` (unless the intention was *both* to reverse it in place and return the new list, which in my opinion is a misleading behavior).

Comment: @DavidRobinson Confusing for someone conversant in Python (or many other languages) yes, but I've seen lots of questions from people that expect in place operations to return `self`.  OP also wrapped `isinstance` in another function, which most experienced Python programmers I've seen would consider redundant...

Comment: @sr2222: In any case, the fact that the OP both used `reversed` and created an entirely new list `o` in the function give every indication he's not looking for an in-place solution.

Comment: worth putting in the standard test for a list ala.> if type(lst) is list:

Comment: @PaulSeeb To the best of my knowledge, `isinstance()` is the preferred way to check if something is an instance of a given class.  It is arguably cleaner, and has the benefit of also matching instances of subclasses.